# Weekly and Monthly financial data from Daily data in r

Tags: r, date, frequency, weekday

I have daily financial data and I want to make them into weekly and monthly. Since they are financial data the week would be 5 days and the month would have 21 days, so `apply.weekly()` and `apply.monthly()` won't work. How can I do this?

A sample data is shown bellow. This is a 12 rows and 30 columns daily data with row names as the dates.

```
dput(NS.JPM[1:12])
structure(c(0.66387295970125, 0.653858704890406, 0.64907263290313, 
0.649654158263102, 0.638678312848259, 0.630628387157003, 0.623044042151063, 
0.630422164453292, 0.614381601026091, 0.606991263875489, 0.603756179397027, 
0.613312175164831, 1.303950618839, 1.25928337004024, 1.26243556927883, 
1.29050198015751, 1.27854397592822, 1.25492247556914, 1.22018717113774, 
1.21577345110274, 1.18286169236707, 1.16219890450654, 1.16432483604233, 
1.16138018587401, 2.12842663080306, 2.07826875092797, 2.08064424580877, 
2.11638773710192, 2.1063098288256, 2.07653655346675, 2.03007842291841, 
2.0331414755819, 1.99331226713788, 1.96894918336452, 1.96894236721977, 
1.95971351201843, 2.83459459742741, 2.78738104558579, 2.78694206476252, 
2.82384475702681, 2.81599157731619, 2.78366577411225, 2.73170887699221, 
2.74560357792116, 2.70274348392311, 2.67782794933003, 2.67422880644078, 
2.66153539308969, 3.38168611364417, 3.33909617054755, 3.33581834809557, 
3.3719599416391, 3.3660185473149, 3.33254736590429, 3.27772171854152, 
3.30136441302715, 3.257042698867, 3.23250079240197, 3.22557769201897, 
3.21078768338538, 3.79555074681395, 3.75728164433049, 3.75162493850528, 
3.78660774478071, 3.7821787193564, 3.74813349654821, 3.69162660233766, 
3.72312009714076, 3.67800421152736, 3.65402663957122, 3.64439896779145, 
3.62822937438674, 4.11022911412854, 4.07555117914885, 4.06799974933419, 
4.10188485222368, 4.0986303176271, 4.06425727701282, 4.00665371980531, 
4.04429359541379, 3.99868961521078, 3.97524579493098, 3.96349110792538, 
3.94634926775623, 4.35352168426666, 4.32173644551182, 4.31268745868885, 
4.34564157626587, 4.3433044314801, 4.30871921649566, 4.2503367914121, 
4.29279600086585, 4.24685862509434, 4.22386723629666, 4.21044122592698, 
4.19257683851448, 4.54550659594692, 4.51604844967222, 4.50580523568339, 
4.53799323116027, 4.53638357908222, 4.50164671908748, 4.442676071188, 
4.48896399874398, 4.44278035199812, 4.42016118728157, 4.40540605769768, 
4.38698264401046, 4.70013181317974, 4.67256489353512, 4.66135507334544, 
4.69291400564735, 4.69189164259347, 4.65703867892447, 4.59760435936681, 
4.64698577914311, 4.6006102106903, 4.57829664680823, 4.56246712032206, 
4.54359772367746, 4.82703185353512, 4.80102351801651, 4.78901859255311, 
4.82005667715528, 4.81951681833008, 4.78457086566622, 4.72475985329676, 
4.77668382801801, 4.73015319716037, 4.70809265055732, 4.69137987989526, 
4.67214608902575, 4.93292692575433, 4.90822164264836, 4.89555253186037, 
4.92615424546666, 4.92601722189509, 4.89099454277976, 4.83087064490883, 
4.88491774052217, 4.83825864129848, 4.81641007033713, 4.79895968747712, 
4.77942243297413, 5.02258446498031, 4.99898335463246, 4.98575164203208, 
5.01598324070536, 5.01618735755936, 4.98110004560984, 4.9207117884182, 
4.97655698967482, 4.92978947107393, 4.90812068887594, 4.89004558273249, 
4.87025162857127, 5.09945386419228, 5.07679978294875, 5.0630856164108, 
5.09299964432716, 5.09349627162482, 5.05835366925581, 4.99773896585608, 
5.05512600473568, 5.00826566266182, 4.98675114447793, 4.96814034096682, 
4.94812638831969, 5.16608146363088, 5.14424836326639, 5.13011598652658, 
5.15975466323401, 5.16050483843027, 5.12531435869301, 5.06450345746245, 
5.12322698067438, 5.07628623197467, 5.05490546888377, 5.03583031224828, 
5.0156257056435, 5.22438337653797, 5.20326871729952, 5.18877037557056, 
5.21816807398139, 5.21914011802633, 5.1839077609438, 5.12292520746191, 
5.18281823815523, 5.13580714879325, 5.11454344365807, 5.09506194751076, 
5.07469052302632, 5.27582726442871, 5.25534655465956, 5.24052529110158, 
5.26971034447129, 5.27087816050615, 5.23560885856043, 5.1744748550151, 
5.23539983515351, 5.18832668615984, 5.16716627574474, 5.14732623339451, 
5.12680761830311, 5.32155554360322, 5.30163835592837, 5.28653004645926, 
5.31552607564195, 5.31686791321033, 5.28156577352498, 5.22029715061659, 
5.28213943067932, 5.23501111967988, 5.2139425298768, 5.19378377558342, 
5.17313432501512, 5.36247045982107, 5.34305748037681, 5.3276923387665, 
5.35651923867756, 5.35801678045937, 5.32268526043485, 5.26129618970976, 
5.32395921608261, 5.2767815503908, 5.2557951170175, 5.23535119784706, 
5.21458468418967, 5.39929393621153, 5.38033474575124, 5.36473845462506, 
5.39341313731308, 5.39505081315946, 5.35969285112576, 5.29819537777039, 
5.36159707740453, 5.31437499278214, 5.2934625006207, 5.27276193248329, 
5.25189006213282, 5.43261043398769, 5.41406181509699, 5.39825638847653, 
5.42679335049413, 5.42855781440451, 5.39317592875818, 5.33158037698304, 
5.3956504006296, 5.34838812755968, 5.32754253474751, 5.30660976018812, 
5.28564256714792, 5.46289816630676, 5.44472279451374, 5.42872724463601, 
5.45713900592345, 5.45901873174746, 5.42361509740318, 5.36193038348416, 
5.4266079746313, 5.37930916664942, 5.35852439148589, 5.33738052010016, 
5.31632667008147, 5.49055218538153, 5.47271760449686, 5.45654846378917, 
5.48484591132177, 5.4868308762981, 5.45140738446212, 5.38964126164987, 
5.45487358842107, 5.40754142249107, 5.38681217650662, 5.36547556451107, 
5.34434259290786, 5.51590170382989, 5.49837951464081, 5.48205124899464, 
5.51024390890209, 5.51232534310646, 5.47688364857537, 5.41504290095201, 
5.48078373540819, 5.43342099136463, 5.41274264713566, 5.39122935623698, 
5.37002385651632, 5.53922326115779, 5.52198847233958, 5.50551381174592, 
5.53361006703214, 5.53578025292818, 5.50032181191967, 5.43841240947294, 
5.50462107101023, 5.45723019510424, 5.43659868049327, 5.41492284499972, 
5.39365061941163, 5.56075085266849, 5.54378135650437, 5.52717156211153, 
5.55517882851433, 5.55743093904954, 5.52195703975494, 5.45998426362616, 
5.52662476555005, 5.47920792177181, 5.45861963450163, 5.4367937578421, 
5.41545993914585, 5.58068380781935, 5.56395995300309, 5.54722503472157, 
5.57514990400927, 5.57747787069211, 5.54198965816993, 5.47995820270631, 
5.5469985568415, 5.49955766873738, 5.47900940678316, 5.45704460311756, 
5.43565375376569, 5.59919298047727, 5.58269722119887, 5.56584611644907, 
5.59369447412958, 5.59609287866389, 5.56059137528764, 5.49850543187038, 
5.56591707734518, 5.51845386236714, 5.49794276677788, 5.47584895946358, 
5.45440515307438, 5.6164256584757, 5.60014226400861, 5.58318298565034, 
5.61096010838612, 5.61342409298907, 5.57791021536941, 5.51577354178847, 
5.5835308723038, 5.53604687023629, 5.51557037781446, 5.49335646365474, 
5.4718633524377, 5.63250949127666, 5.61642430396686, 5.599364063574, 
5.62707470036131, 5.62959989302834, 5.59407446611484, 5.53189044438116, 
5.59997041426774, 5.55246701091673, 5.53202281478452, 5.50969680090239, 
5.48815767184603), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1302840000, 
1303099200, 1303185600, 1303272000, 1303358400, 1303704000, 1303790400, 
1303876800, 1303963200, 1304049600, 1304308800, 1304395200), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(12L, 30L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", 
"X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", 
"X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", "X29", 
"X30")))
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include an example of your data in your post.  Use the `dput` function to generate a short sample that we can work with.

Comment: I have done so, thank you. @WaltS

Comment: What is shown in an xts object.    It does not have row names.  The dates are stored in an attribute. The xts package has to.weekly and to.monthly .

Comment: If I use those functions, it takes 7 days of data as weekly. I need 5 points of data to be one week. I have put the screenshot of how the data looks, which has row names. @G.Grothendieck

Comment: It takes 7 calendar days, not 7 days.  Since there are no values on the weekend this is 5 days of data.  It does not have row names. rownames(X) is NULL but time(X) and index(X) give the dates where X is the object.  It shows the time/index to the left of the data when you print it out but that does not mean that they are row names.

Comment: What about monthly ones? Is it 21 days? Also, do I need to omit the first data point, which is Friday or would the function automatically remove it, since it's a single point from previous week? Thank you. @G.Grothendieck

Comment: For monthly it is a calendar month.  However, many days of data are in each month will be included.  You can delete days you don't want prior to using to.monthly if desired.

Comment: Both `to.weekly` and `apply.weekly` will properly divide the data into weeks.  `to.weekly` gives you the open, high, low, and close (OHLC) values for each week. The close value is the value at the close of the last trading day of the week.  For example, in your data, the  last trading day of the second week 2011-04-20, a Thursday,  because the market was closed on the next day for the Good Friday holiday.   `to.monthly` would give only one value.  What would you like to see for each week?